# sitemap for multilingual page

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.x

I try to create a sitemap for a typo3 installation with multible languages. I tried like 10 extensions and noone of them seems to fit. Some of them create the sitemap just for the default language. Some of them create links for all languages, but they also create links to pages that are not translated at all.

Idealy I would like to output a sitemap like this: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2620865?hl=en

And only add links to other languages if that page exists in that language. Also we do not use the default language at all. So I just want the localized links in it.

I also tried to create something with fluid and then output it as XML, without good success.

Any idea how to archive that?

**Edit** (this edit belongs to the answer of Jozef Spisiak and his changes to seo_basics)

The changed seo_basics from Jozef Spisiak output following code:

Config:

```
tx_seo_xmlsitemaps.10.sysLanguageHrefLangMappings {
    # sys_language_uid = hreflang
    1 = de-ch
    4 = de-at
    12 = de
}
```

Output:

```
<url>
    <loc>http://domain.com/</loc>
    <lastmod>2016-10-13T17:53:56+02:00</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>http://domain.com/home/</loc>
    <lastmod>2016-06-27T15:25:24+02:00</lastmod>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="" href="http://domain.com/home/" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-ch" href="http://domain.com/ch/home/" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-at" href="http://domain.com/at/home/" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://domain.com/de/home/" />
</url>
<url>
    <loc>http://domain.com/ch/home/</loc>
    <lastmod>2016-06-27T15:25:24+02:00</lastmod>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="" href="http://domain.com/home/" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-ch" href="http://domain.com/ch/home/" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-at" href="http://domain.com/at/home/" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://domain.com/de/home/" />
</url>
<url>
    <loc>http://domain.com/at/home/</loc>
    <lastmod>2016-06-27T15:25:24+02:00</lastmod>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="" href="http://domain.com/home/" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-ch" href="http://domain.com/ch/home/" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-at" href="http://domain.com/at/home/" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://domain.com/de/home/" />
</url>
<url>
    <loc>http://domain.com/de/home/</loc>
    <lastmod>2016-06-27T15:25:24+02:00</lastmod>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="" href="http://domain.com/home/" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-ch" href="http://domain.com/ch/home/" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-at" href="http://domain.com/at/home/" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://domain.com/de/home/" />
</url>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using seo_basics and created this feature together with typoscript configuration on which languages to show in sitemap. You can check the code here: https://github.com/pixelant/t3ext-seo_basics/

For configuration, check commented out section of typoscript setup. We also created pull request, but it is still waiting for feedback:
https://github.com/b13/t3ext-seo_basics/pull/30

Comment: Oh this looks great, I will come definitely back to this

Comment: I installed and tested the extension and it looks very nice so far ( I posted the output in the original Post). The only downside is that we do not use the default language for anything but the landingpage. Is there any way to exclude the default language?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me: hreflang="". Maybe you can try to filter it out by adding some condition into the code?

Comment: feel free to add pull request afterwards, it will update a pull request to the main repository after we merge it.

Comment: This comes because I did not add a hreflang for the default language (sys_lang_uid=0). Yes I guess I will edit the controller and try to filter out the sys_lang_uid=0 links (and also the links it generates to pages inside a folder). Anyway thanks for the code, I hope he accepts the pull request.

Comment: Thanks again for the code. Its perfect. All I did was add a `if` on line 137 of the controller to only add the landing page in the default lang: `if($item[uid] == 1)`. And that just because we do not use the default language as a real language. So I have nothing for a pull request.